# How to align xticks of multiple subplot vertically?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I try to plot 3 subplots from a specific rows of a dataframe I get a weird result that the third subplot has a different spacing in the xticks even though the start of the plot seems to be correct.
I presume it could have something to do with the datasince FE 57 and FE 59 both start at an index close to 0 and FE 66 stars at an index at 3600.
Is there a way to plot all with white space starting from 0 so that all the xticks align vertically with each other?

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1)
ser = plotdf[(plotdf['CAN_address'] == 'FE 57') & (plotdf['CAN_cmd'] == 62)]['CAN_value_translated']
axs[0].plot(ser.index, ser.values)
axs[0].set_title('FE 57')

ser = plotdf[(plotdf['CAN_address'] == 'FE 59') & (plotdf['CAN_cmd'] == 62)]['CAN_value_translated']
axs[1].plot(ser.index, ser.values)
axs[1].set_title('FE 59')

ser = plotdf[(plotdf['CAN_address'] == 'FE 66') & (plotdf['CAN_cmd'] == 62)]['CAN_value_translated']
axs[2].plot(ser.index, ser.values)
axs[2].set_title('FE 66')

plt.show()
```

[image: moved xticks in the last plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You should instantiate the subplots using the keyword argument `sharex=...`.
You can specify the value as `'all'`, `'row'`, `'col'`, `'none'`, that make sense if you think of a 2D arrangement of subplots.
I said "you should" and not "you must" because sharing the *x*-axis places the x tick labels only on the bottom subplot, and you may disagree with that.

The image above was generated as

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex='col')

ax0.plot((0, 7),(1, 12))
ax1.plot((-7,0),(1, -2))
plt.show()
```

If you don't like the labels only on the bottom, you can do like this (image below)

```
fig, (ax0, ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=3)

ax0.plot((0, 7),(1, 12))
ax1.plot((-7,0),(1, -2))
ax2.plot((-3,5),(-5,10))

# collect the lower and upper bounds of the x-axes
xmins, xmaxs = zip(*(ax.get_xlim() for ax in (ax0, ax1, ax2)))

# .set_xlim accepts a tuple, that we compute here
xlim = (min(xmins), max(xmaxs))

# finally, we set the same xlim on all the x-axes
for ax in (ax0, ax1, ax2):
    ax.set_xlim(xlim)

plt.show()
```

[image]

PS if the y-data on the plots is "the same", I'd recommend that you use also `sharey=...`, so that the comparison between different instances is immediate (even better, plot the y-data in the same subplot).

Comment: Works like a charm! Even gives a little extra room in front and behind and scales to the data.
Even solved my solution to only have the labels from the last plot visible in a better way.

The y data differs so it needs to be different.

Comment: @Anjo Well, looking at your data (spectroscopy?) I'd rather use plt.logy(x, y0, label='FE57')` etc, all in a single plot, but I don't know of particular conventions in your field :-)

Comment: Yes I already plotted them all in one plot but since one goes up to 800 the other two get squished and are hardly distinguishable. And since the data doesn't correlate with each other this is the best option. No it's not spectroscopy but rather oxigen and nitrogen oxide measures.

Comment: @Anjo My suggestion was to plot everything on the same Axes, but using a **logarithmic** _y_-axis, `plt.semilogy(x, y0, label='FE57')` etc etc

Answer (score 1):

You can set the limits of you axes with `set_xlim()`:

```
x_min = -1000
x_max = 51000

for ax in axs:
  ax.set_xlim((x_min, x_max))
```